# View removed files between revisions in perforce

Tags: perforce

Can anyone point me to how i can view files that have been removed between revisions in Perforce? i am a new user and the latest revision has some build failures due to missing files that must have been left out in the previous revision. I need an easy way to identify these files.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the command line or the gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use P4V's Folder Diff.  From the command line you can run `p4 diff2` and look for cases where the file is present in one revision but not the other.